# How to copy data from one sheet to another in Google Spreadsheet, and delete the copied data afterwards?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I receive Google Form data from various users on a daily basis, and the data are stored in a Google Spreadsheet. I'm trying to copy the collected data (except the header row) to my target sheet, but more specifically:

1. Copy and paste the data from Sheet1 to the next row of the data in Sheet2.
2. Delete the copied data in Sheet1 when copying is completed, so I can make sure I don't overwrite data and keep the sheet clean.

I'm not familiar with coding at all, and this is what I came up with:

```
function Copy() {

    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sourceid');
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var range = ss.getRange('A:H');
    var data = range.getValues();
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sourceid');
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

It gives me an error stating that the number of data row is 1000 whereas the number of the range is 8. I think it's the last line that's causing the problem.

Comment: The arguments of `getRange` are `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. So how about modifying from `ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);` to `ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)

Comment: As Tanaike said, you need to specify in order `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. There are multiple ways of calling `getRange()` on a sheet and currently your script uses the [three parameter method call](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows) `getRange(row, column, numRows)`.